# Can I call from one ejb3 session bean method to other method in same session bean ?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

Can I call from one ejb3 session bean (statless/statefull) method to other method in same session bean ? does state of members will be save between calls ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  Use `@Resource SessionContext` to inject an instance, and then use the getBusinessObject (or getEJBObject or getEJBLocalObject depending on which view you want); see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html) for those methods.

For stateless beans, the invocation will be on a new bean instance.  Depending on what you're trying to do, it can be even simpler to use `@EJB YourInterface` to directly inject the proxy rather than using SessionContext.

For stateful beans, the state of the bean will be "preserved" because you'll be invoking the same underlying bean instance.